# How to assert mockery shouldReceive

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to implement middleware unit test using Mockery

```
public function handle() {
            // create user
            $user = factory(User::class)->create();

            // log in as admin user
            $this->be($user, 'api');

            $response = \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse')->shouldReceive('getContent', 'setData')->once()->andReturn(json_encode(['data' => [], 'meta' => []]))->getMock();
            $request = Request::create('/admin/customers', 'GET');

            $middlewareResponse = $this->middleware->handle($request, function () use ($response) {
                return $response;
            });

            print_r($middlewareResponse); exit;
    }
```

How can I get `setData` and perform assertion?

here is the `middlewareResponse`

```
[_mockery_receivedMethodCalls:protected] => Mockery\ReceivedMethodCalls Object
        (
            [methodCalls:Mockery\ReceivedMethodCalls:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mockery\MethodCall Object
                        (
                            [method:Mockery\MethodCall:private] => getContent
                            [args:Mockery\MethodCall:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Mockery\MethodCall Object
                        (
                            [method:Mockery\MethodCall:private] => setData
                            [args:Mockery\MethodCall:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [data] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [meta] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [home] => /customer/test/dashboard/consectetur-architecto-nostrum
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Here is my HomePage middleware

```
class HomePage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        // get original response
        $response = $next($request);
        $responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

        $data['meta'] = [
            'home' => null,
        ];

        //print_r($response);exit;
        if($response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            // get banner meta data
            $data['meta'] = $this->getHomePageUrl();
        }

        // merge meta data into original
        $payloadWithMeta = array_merge_recursive($responseData, $data);

        $response->setData($payloadWithMeta);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * generate dashboard url for user's first customer of first profile
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getHomePageUrl() {
        // first initialise an empty profile
        $profile = null;

        // fetch user's first customer
        $user = Auth::user();
        $customer = $user->customers()->orderBy('title')->first();

        // set profile if customer found
        if($customer) {
            $customer->activateDatabase();

            $profile = Profile::orderBy('title')->first();
        }

        return [
            'home' => $profile ? 'customer/settings' : null
        ];
    }
}
```

``

Comment: Can you show original middleware or code you want to test? As it stands here seems like you misunderstands what mockery can do, but let's help that in the right direction :)

Comment: @mrhn Thanks for your response, I have added middleware code. I would like to assert `home` here